# Upload large files with node js

Tags: node.js, http, express

I try to upload large files with Node js.
But when the file is large the servers returns an error : "Request aborted" and in my Chrome console, I've  :
"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET."

I use formidable to get the file in my route.
The timeout of my server is about 1hour, so it's not that.. Or perhaps when its a big file, nodejs doesnt take my timeout..

The upload block at 2minutes.

I try all the solution...

Help me please :)

Pierrick

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: It starts with files larger than 70Mb. And my connection is very slow, so it's perhaps linked..

Comment: Hard to give feedback on your code without any... code.  But you'll likely find one or more things here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502631/node-js-server-not-responding-while-large-file-upload-with-express-and-busboy

Comment: It's an other problem now.. In fact, many files are received to the server, but files with extensions (.img for my issue) doesnt pass... Is there a configuration for accept all the files ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in nodejs underlying libraries. I hope this helps https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4266